# TypeScript Generic Type in getDeepValue

Tags: typescript, generics

Here are the correct code snippets:

```
export const getDeepValue = <T, TFK extends keyof T, TSK extends keyof T[TFK]>(
  obj: T,
  firstKey: TFK,
  secondKey: TSK
) => {
  return obj[firstKey][secondKey];
};
const obj = {
  foo: {
    a: true,
    b: 2,
  },
  bar: {
    c: "12",
    d: 18,
  },
};

const value = getDeepValue(obj, "foo", "a");
```

Here are my version of `getDeepValue`:

```
export const getDeepValue = <T, >(
  obj: T,
  firstKey: keyof T,
  secondKey: keyof T[keyof T]
) => {
  return obj[firstKey][secondKey];
};

const obj = {
  foo: {
    a: true,
    b: 2,
  },
  bar: {
    c: "12",
    d: 18,
  },
};

const value = getDeepValue(obj, "foo", "a");
```

And my code always give me an error that `secondKey` is `never` type.

What's different between using `extends` or not using it?

Why can't I use `keyof T[keyof T]` for `secondKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T[keyof T]` doesn't work because Typescript cannot infer that the parameter `keyof T` is the same as the return `keyof T`.

You can use a second type parameter `U` that extends `keyof T` and adjust the return type to `T[U]`, which infers that the parameter `keyof T` is the same as the return `keyof T`

```
export const getDeepValue = <T,U extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  firstKey: U,
  secondKey: keyof T[U]
) => {
  return obj[firstKey][secondKey];
};

const obj = {
  foo: {
    a: true,
    b: 2,
  },
  bar: {
    c: "12",
    d: 18,
  },
};

const value = getDeepValue(obj, "foo", "a");
```

Comment: I still have some confuse in `Typescript cannot infer that the parameter keyof T is the same as the return keyof T.`
So can I understand that it's one of the TypeScript mechanisms?

Comment: @Jason Yes, `keyof T` can be any key of `T`, so there's no assurance that the `keyof T` in the return `T[keyof T]` is the same as in the eparameter.